# finding percentage of a conditional group from the total at a column related to an event range from different column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataset like below :

How can I find  the percentage of employees  terminated at 2022 that First hire at 2021 from total employee  using pandas?

| employee No | Event date | Event Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2021-10-12 | First Hire |
| 103 | 2021-11-02 | First Hire |
| 102 | 2022-01-01 | Terminated |
| 102 | 2021-12-12 | Shift Change |
| 101 | 2021-12-03 | First Hire |
| 103 | 2021-11-05 | Terminated |
| 101 | 2021-12-04 | Terminated |
| 105 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire |
| 106 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire |
| 102 | 2022-03-29 | Second Hire |
| 107 | 2021-05-04 | First Hire |
| 108 | 2022-04-04 | First Hire |
| 109 | 2022-03-03 | Terminated |
| 109 | 2021-12-29 | First Hire |
| 109 | 2022-04-01 | Second Hire |
| 109 | 2022-01-10 | Shift Change |

at the sample dataset Desired Condition belong to employee 109 and 102 how can find the condition at a dataset with 2M records .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Convert Event Date to Timestamp if it's not Timestamp already
df["Event date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Event date"])

# First hired in 2021
cond1 = df["Event date"].dt.year.eq(2021) & df["Event Description"].eq("First Hire")

# Terminated in 2022 & first hired in 2021
cond2 = (
    df["Event date"].dt.year.eq(2022)
    & df["Event Description"].eq("Terminated")
    & df["employee No"].isin(df.loc[cond1, "employee No"])
)

df[cond2]
```